# Restore /etc/hosts on SuSE

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse, sles

I have lost my `/etc/hosts` file on SuSE Enterprise 11.3 64 bit. Is there any way to get the original file back?

Comment: How did you manage to lose it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample default ip v4 & v6 */etc/hosts* :

```
# Loopback devices
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 localhost
# IPv6
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Answer (score 0):

just rewrite it from scratch. Unless you had lots of modifications, its usually only a few lines. `127.0.0.1 localhost` will usually be enough.